# Show Fastlane Spaceship sandbox logs when running script

Tags: ruby, logging, fastlane

When I run the Fastlane Spaceship sandbox via `bundle exec fastlane spaceship` there are pretty nice and useful logs showing what is happening during the process and on which step it is currently.

I'm using Thor to run a Spaceship script on its own as CLI, and I would like to have those same logs shown during the process. Is there a way to do that?

The logs of each run can be found after the process is finished but they are different from the ones shown in the sandbox and pretty verbose.